# changing #define in util class while app is running

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor

Assuming Macros is a custom util class which can be accessed from any view.

How Can I change #define APP_THEME_COLOR while the app is running? 
(For example, user can change this color)

```
//
//  Macros.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//App Specific

#define APP_THEME_COLOR [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 / 255 green:0.0 / 255 blue:0.0 / 255 alpha:0.9]
```

*(As a side question, what do you think would be the best way to implement such functionality in an app? , I feel uncomfortable with #define)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#define` is applied at compile time only.  All it does is substitute one string for another.  If you want to change values at run time, create a method that takes parameters...or use the code directly with variables instead of literal constants.

Comment: What part of the process do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change what's being `#define`d during runtime, since these declarations are evaluated even before the compiling took place.

You could define a color variable in your app delegate and notify your UI components if it has changed.

See this [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/) on how to achieve this.